# Insert new line before each occurance of specified fomat within databound textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, eval

I have a TemplateField in my asp page that binds to a column with datatype of string called Descript which stores note entries for a help desk ticket appending the newest note at the beginning of the string.

```
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Notes" SortExpression="DESCRIPT">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DESCRIPT") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DESCRIPT") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Within this Descript string is likely to be several occurances of a date and time followed by a time zone, a hyphen, a name and then some text.

eg:

12/4/2015 8:34 AM Central Standard Time - Last, First

What I am looking to do is insert a new line (or 2) before this information each time something of the same pattern occurs to give some visual break when each new entry occurs.

My guess is that I need to use RegEx to match the date/time pattern and store in a variable and later replace that information with a new line + variable.

something like this:

```
string text = Descript.ToString();
string pattern = @"/[0-1]\d\/[0-3]\d\/\d{4} [0-1]\d:[0-5]\d [aApP][mM]/";

Regex r = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Match m = r.Match(text);
while (m.Success)
{
  //here is where I am stuck
  //I expect to have something like Replace (found string) with Environment.NewLine + (found string)
}
```

If I can modify my SQL select statement I am more than happy to do so.

```
Select ID, Name, Descript
From Table
```

This SQL statement may return in excess of 100 records, and the date time pattern may exist several times in each Descript record.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a "backreference." These are described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972966.aspx (search for "backreference")

In your example:

```
newText = Regex.Replace(text, pattern, "\n\1")
```

(note that some regex implementations treat the whole match as `\0`)

The backreference, in this case `\1,` represents the original string found, which in your case, is the time and date. In effect this is saying, take whatever was found, and replace it with a newline followed by whatever was found.